# betwenness centrality in larg graph

Tags: python, graph, social-networking, large-data, node-centrality

I have a dataset with 30000 nodes and many edges. I can't get output with betwenness centrality and closeness in python. I get a VM with high config and try it but don't give output.
Is there any way to run and get output for centrality?

Comment: Add your code to see what's the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.